# User flair image should be served over SSL as well

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flair, ssl, security

Unfortunately, the current flair image is only served over plain HTTP. Naturally, if you embed it directly on a page served over SSL, you will get mixed content warning from your browser.

Please serve the image over SSL too.

Comment: I think this has been resolved as I can access the flair image over HTTPS either using a protocol-relative URL on an HTTPS site or by explicitly specifying the `https:` scheme.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 it's not about the single image but the HTML flair

Answer (score 1):

Flair is now served over HTTPS for all Q&A sites, enjoy!